# Swift textfield text 1 to 9 if user entered need to show alert

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying simple logic, I have only one textfield. into this textfield if user entered 1 to 9 I need to show alert using if.

```
if emailTextField.text < 0 {
    print("100%")
}
```

Comment: This doesn't compile: *Binary operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String?' and 'Int'*. You are comparing apples (optional String) with oranges (Integer).

Comment: please give some sample code.@vadian

Comment: shouldn't an email be an email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UITextField`'s `text` is always a `String`. So if you need to check if it is a particular number, you need to cast the `String` value to an `Int`.

```
if let number = Int(emailTextField.text!), (0...9).contains(number) {
    print("100%)
}
```

Note: You might want to check out the [`UITextFieldDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate) methods if your logic revolves around text field editing events.

```
yourTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(valueChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
.
.
.
@objc func valueChanged(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if let number = Int(emailTextField.text!), (0...9).contains(number) {
        print("100%)
    }
}
```

Sidenote: I have no idea what your use case is for this.

Comment: nice answer thank you. May i know who to print this while user enter 0 to 9 values. Which method i need focus? @Rakesha Shastri

Comment: @Alexa You have register your textField to listen to the notification for value changes.

Comment: no bro. I didn't. please let me know how to show alert while user edit 1 to 9 numbers@ Rakesha Shastri

Comment: @Alexa you need to do some reading then. :x

Comment: Live reading bro. while user enter number to show alert or print. @Rakesha Shastri